# Objective-C Class keyword and Protocols

Tags: objective-c

What does it mean in Objective-C if you try to mix Class and Protocol? I'm trying to get the complier to warn me at compiler time if a class doesn't conform to a protocol.  For example:

```
@protocol FLLiveDataProtocol <NSObject>
...
@end

- (id)initWithDataPath:(NSString *)path usingDataClassFactory:(Class<FLLiveDataProtocol>)dataFactoryClass;
```

However, I get all kind of interesting issues when I try this.  First, it doesn't trigger a compiler error if you pass in a class that doesn't conform to the protocol, second you will get errors such as "No know class method for selector alloc" if you try to do [[dataFactoryClass] alloc] init] even through the protocol conforms to NSObject.

I haven't seen many examples of people trying to mix protocol's and the Class keyword (I should say Typedef -- thanks Nikolai).

I know I can use conformsToProtocol to check at runtime, but it would be nice if I could get this to check at compile time.

Comment: Actually, conformsToProtocol at runtime won't even tell you for sure -- for that you'd need to do respondsToSelector on each relevant method.  (This is the back side of "duck typing" -- the only way to know it's NOT a duck is to note that it doesn't look or walk or quack like one.)

Comment: I think your trying to solve the wrong problem. Why does your data factory have to be a class? It will be a lot easier if you an instance?

Comment: I'm using a standard Factory pattern because I need it to create multiple instances based on the given factory class.

Comment: I'm using the @required keyword in the Protocol (not shown above) so I will get a compile time error if it doesn't implement the expected methods.  That gives me a reasonable level of comfort when using conformsToProtocol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no static type information for class objects in Objective-C ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17300253/104790)), so there's no way to express the need for a class to conform to a protocol.

Side note: `Class` is not a keyword but a typedef in objc.h:

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

Comment: Do you know what the syntax Class<FLLiveDataProtocol> means to the compiler?  It doesn't given an error when using that syntax.

Comment: It's like `id<FLLiveDataProtocol>` except it'll warn if something known not to be a class (eg. `NSArray *<FLLiveDataProtocol>`) is passed in.

Answer (score 1):

> second you will get errors such as "No know class method for selector
>   alloc" if you try to do [[dataFactoryClass] alloc] init] even through
>   the protocol conforms to NSObject.

The reason for this is that neither your protocol or the [NSObject protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) declare `+alloc`. You could fix this by adding an `+alloc` method (or some other class method that returns a new instance) to your protocol declaration.

Comment: Wow, this is really interesting.  I had assumed alloc would have been defined by NSObject.  I need to read more about the ObjC runtime.  Alloc is implemented by an NSProxy class which uses attributes to attach itself to the NS_ROOT_CLASS.  Very interesting.  I will have to try defining an alloc method in the protocol to see what happens.

Comment: Not sure why you think the Obj-C runtime is relevant here. `+alloc` is implemented by the *class* NSObject (and, independently, by the NSProxy class), it just isn't declared in the NSObject protocol (which they both conform to). Likely your class does implement +alloc, but the static type `Class<MyProtocol>` doesn't communicate this to the compiler.

Comment: Although I agree, it's odd that the NSObject protocol doesn't declare it.